# Python Structlog JSON

Tags: python, python-3.8, structlog

I am currently using the python [structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/) JSONRenderer and hoping to change my log configuration to render the event as the 1st JSON attribute for better readability.

Current Configuration:

```
structlog.configure(processors=[structlog.processors.JSONRenderer()])
log = structlog.get_logger()
```

Current log call site:

```
log.msg("Response: ",
                        content_type=content_type,
                        content_length=resp.headers.get('content-length'),
                        status_code=resp.status_code
                )
```

Current Output:

```
{"content_type": "application/json", "content_length": null, "status_code": 200, "event": "Response: "}
```

Desired Output:

```
{"event": "Response: ", "content_type": "application/json", "content_length": null, "status_code": 200}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? The order of the key value pairs really don't matter in json or dictionaries. (kwargs use dictionaries hence are not ordered)

Comment: Yeah key value pairs order shouldn't really matter once imported into a logging tool etc just handy to have the log message output 1st to reduce impact of structured logging when running locally & being read by humans. Thinking I am probably better off to use a separate more human readable format for this going forward though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `structlog.processors.JSONRenderer` just passes the log object to `json.dumps` unless you specify another callable instead:

```
structlog.configure(processors=[structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(serializer=mydumps)])
```

The `mydumps` will then be a function that does what `json.dumps` does but puts `event` first. This could look like:

```
def mydumps(dic,**kw):
   mod = {}
   if 'event' in dic:
      mod["event"] = dic["event"]
   for k in dic:
      if k!="event":
         mod[k] = dic[k]
   return json.dumps(mod,**kw)
```

What it does is to make a new object then look for `event` key in the input object and put it first to the new object then proceeding to put rest of keys into the object and pass it along with `**kw` to `json.dumps`.

Note that this way you would not need to specify beforehand what other keys your logs might have (like content-type) as any event type might have different info.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might be using an older version of python than 3.6 which keeps keys ordered in insertion order. You can use the `KeyValueRenderer` to set the key order and use `OrderedDict` as the context_class:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer(
            key_order=["event", "content_type", "content_length", "status_code"]
        ),
        structlog.processors.JSONRenderer()
    ],
    context_class = OrderedDict
)
log = structlog.get_logger()
```

Reference: [KeyValueRenderer](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer)

Answer (score 0):

I merged and improved upon both answers by re-using what is already in a structlog.

The approved answer used a custom json dump method that I want to avoid, the other solution has the side-effect of converting log from JSON to string, losing a lot of usefulness.

Complete example of mine that works both in local shell and remote server would be:

```
import collections
import logging
import sys

import orjson
import structlog
from structlog.typing import EventDict, WrappedLogger


class ForcedKeyOrderRenderer(structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer):
    """Based upon KeyValueRenderer but returns dict instead of string."""

    def __call__(self, _: WrappedLogger, __: str, event_dict: EventDict) -> str:
        sorted_dict = self._ordered_items(event_dict)
        return collections.OrderedDict(**{key: value for key, value in sorted_dict})


shared_processors = [
    structlog.contextvars.merge_contextvars,
    structlog.processors.add_log_level,
    structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", utc=True),
]

if sys.stderr.isatty():
    processors = shared_processors + [
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.dev.set_exc_info,
        structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(),
    ]
    logger_factory = None
else:  # pragma: no cover
    processors = shared_processors + [
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.processors.dict_tracebacks,
        ForcedKeyOrderRenderer(
            sort_keys=True,
            key_order=[
                "event",
                "content_type",
                "content_length",
                "status_code",
            ],
            drop_missing=True,
        ),
        structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(serializer=orjson.dumps),
    ]
    logger_factory = structlog.BytesLoggerFactory()

if not structlog.is_configured():
    structlog.configure(
        cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
        wrapper_class=structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(logging.INFO),
        processors=processors,
        logger_factory=logger_factory,
    )

logger = structlog.get_logger()
```